# How to prevent Actions & Notificatins bar from accidental dragging in UWP Phone app

Tags: c#, uwp, monogame, uwp-xaml, windows-10-mobile

I'm creating a Windows 10 Mobile game which requires fast swiping in horizontal orientation. Due to that fact player can accidentally expand Actions & Notifications bar:
[image]

Is there a way to prevent this bar from appearing during application runtime? I've seen also in some other apps smaller drag handle:
[image]
How to force switching to this smaller mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you've seen, you can place your app in **full-screen mode** with setting [**FullScreenSystemOverlayMode**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationView_FullScreenSystemOverlayMode) to **Minimal**.

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;

var view = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
view.FullScreenSystemOverlayMode = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Minimal;
```

> In full-screen mode:
>
> - On the mobile device family, the user can swipe from the bottom to bring up the navigation bar (Back, Start, Cortana). **They can also swipe from the top to bring up Action Center.**
> - On the desktop device family, the user can swipe from the bottom to bring up the navigation bar (taskbar). They can swipe from the left to bring up Task View, from the right to bring up Action Center, and from the top to bring up the title bar.
>
> You can **suppress edge swipes and show a small UI instead** by setting [FullScreenSystemOverlayMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationView_FullScreenSystemOverlayMode) to **Minimal**.

For more info, please see **Remarks** and **User experience** under [IsFullScreenMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationView_IsFullScreenMode).